# JavaScript navigation UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I think that the `slice()` is a bit hacky, and prone to breaking if I change my mind about the `id` names, but I wanted this to be generic so I could add types easily.

Is there maybe another / better way to do this just using CSS nesting the 'panels' inside the li elements?

Markup:

```html
   <ul id="type-select">
    <li><a id="type-1" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a id="type-2" href="#">2</a></li>
    ...
   </ul>

   <div id="panel-1" class="panel">blah</div>
   <div id="panel-2" class="panel">blah</div> 
   ...
```

JavaScript:

```js
function switchType(type){
    $("#type-select li a").removeClass("selected-type");
    $("#type-"+type).addClass("selected-type");
    $(".panel").removeClass("selected-panel");
    $("#panel-"+type).addClass("selected-panel");   
}

// initial state
$("#no-results").hide();
switchType("1");
$("#type-select li a").click(function(){switchType(this.id.slice(5))});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This kind of navigation is usually referred to as tabs or tabbed navigation. There are loads of ready scripts on the net for this - for exampe - since you are using jQuery - [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/). But since this is really a quite trivial functionality, it's quite okay to implement it yourself.

To make the implementation cleaner, you can add a direct reference to the matching panel in the link. I would use the `href` attribute and refer to the panel using a URL hash. This has the advantage, that it will work without JavaScript or CSS by scrolling to the chosen panel.

You can drop the `id`s on the links and use a direct reference to them in the function.

```
<ul id="type-select">
  <li><a href="#panel-1">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#panel-2">2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Consider using the CSS `:target` pseudo class for the functionality:

```
.panel { display: none; }
.panel:target { display: block; }
```

And add JavaScript, for browsers that don't support it and to set the classes:

```
$("#type-select li a").click(function(){return switchType(this)});

function switchType(link){
    var hashPos = link.href.indexOf("#");
    if (hashPos >= 0) {
      // Parsing out the hash and removing '#', in case the href
      // attribute contains a complete URL, and in case some other
      // method than a CSS selector is used to find the panel
      var panelId = link.href.substring(hashPos + 1);

      $("#type-select li a").removeClass("selected-type");
      $(link).addClass("selected-type");
      $(".panel").removeClass("selected-panel");
      $("#" + panelId).addClass("selected-panel");   
    }
    return false;
}
```

Don't forget to return `false` so the the default action of the link (which will lead to unnecessary scrolling) is canceled.